# DataGrid bound to Datatable not refreshing Values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatable

I've a DataGrid which is bound to a DataTable ("LastDatasets")

When I refresh the DataTable in a Timer via this code:

```
if (LastDatasets != null)
{
    var maxRow = LastDatasets.Select("id = MAX(id)").FirstOrDefault();

    var newds = dataInterface.ReadFromDatabase("SELECT * FROM daten WHERE id > " + dataInterface.SqlSep + "id LIMIT 30", new Dictionary<string, object>() {{"id", maxRow["id"]}});

    if (newds != null && newds.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        LastDatasets.Merge(newds);
    }               
}
```

My DataTable contains my new data, but the DataGrid in WPF is not refreshed!

Answer (score 1):

i use simple binding and i can see all changes after .Merge(). so you should post some more code to see whats going wrong.

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" />
```

vm.cs

```
 MyDataTable.Merge(newdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading new data call

```
DataGrid.Refresh();
```

Comment: That is no good solution, because then the whole DataGrid gets redrawed, but i only wanted that the changes are drawn. Because the whole redraw is very slow!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using binding then use like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding yourdatasource,IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score -1):

The DataTable doesn't implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so there isn't a way for your DataGrid to be notified when a property changes. If you were to bind your DataGrid to a collection of object's who raised a PropertyChanged event whenever a property was changed you'd see your values update. I believe your solutions are to do what Ask says and `Refresh` the contents of your DataGrid or to bind your DataGrid to a collection of objects who implement INotifyPropety Changed instead of a DataTable.

Another thing to try is to [enable virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization.aspx) on the DataGrid. By default row virtualization should be enabled but you can double check by setting `EnableRowVirtualization = True`. Additionally, set `EnableColumnVirtualization = true` as well.

Comment: did you ever bind a datatable to a wpf datagrid? it works like a charme because its bound to the datagrid as a BindingListCollectionView and this of course has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented

Comment: When a DataRow is modified it calls EndEdit() which in turn calls SetNewRecord on the DataTable. The DataTable then raised the OnRowChanged event which notifies the DataView and updates the binding. The DataTable doesn't implment INotifyPropertyChanged and a single cell value cannot be updated only a row.