# Binding a WPF DataGrid to a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm not good at English because I'm not a native speaker. I apologize if I've made mistakes in the language :)

I'm new in C# and WPF and I'm trying to bind a WPF DataGrid to a DataTable in TwoWay. Now when I edit the values in the DataGrid, data in the DataTable change correctly. When I try to fill the DataTable with the following code:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("a query", (a connection));
adapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

the code works and the DataGrid seems all right. But when I try this:

```
dataTable.Rows[0][1] = (some object);
```

the display value doesn't change. I try to check the values in the DataGrid in the following way:

```
MessageBox.Show((SomeDataGrid.Items[0] as DataRowView).Row[1].ToString());
```

and it turns out no problem. I'm wondering why the display values are like this.

Here's my DataGrid.CellStyle in XAML:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- triggers -->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

I've been stuck on this problem for several days. Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you define the column for DataGrid, Make sure you are setting the UpdateMode property to PropertyChanged

Answer (score 6):

This works, maybe you can give some more info

viewmodel:

```
public DataTable MyDataTable { get; private set; }

//ctor
_ds = new DataSet("Test");
this.MyDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
this.MyDataTable.Columns.Add("First");
this.MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Second");

this.MyDataTable.Rows.Add("11", "12");
this.MyDataTable.Rows.Add("21", "22");

//view is updated with this
public void UpdateTable()
{
    this.MyDataTable.Rows[0][1] = "haha";
}
```

xaml

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not very sure if this solution will work but it is worth a try.

Instead of binding your `DataGrid` to a `DataTable`, try binding it to a `DataView` . You can convert your `DataTable` to a `DataView` using `DefaultView` property like

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
```

On binding with `DataView` your notification to changes in data should work both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't believe the `DataRow` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the `DataTable` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  These are the interface that tell a WPF `DataBinding` to update when the underlying source value changes.  So when you update the underlying `DataTable` values, the `Binding` is not automatically refreshed and the change won't be reflected in your `DataGrid`.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798936/inotifypropertychanged-or-inotifycollectionchanged-with-datatable) points to a similar question and provides an answer.  Basically, if you want your `DataGrid` to recognize and update when you change values in the underlying data source, you'll need to create a custom object/objects that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: afaik wpf is binding to the underlining dataview and so to a IBindingListView and so it has all Notification stuff

Comment: This seems to be a topic of much debate, but if you look at the second  answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154381/datagrid-bound-to-datatable-not-refreshing-values), and specifically the comments it is explained.  The IBindingListView Interface does not replace the need for INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You can also look at [this presentation](http://es.slideshare.net/EyalV/data-binding-in-depth-presentation) by an MVP, slied 24, it states that the items in the IBindingListView collection must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: try my test code. it works and there is no INotifyPropertyChanged implemented