# Wpf DataGrid data binding with arbitrary colums and rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

For one of my projects, I'm trying to load data from a file (for example a *.csv) and displaying it in a `DataGrid` . The format of the file is not given. For example, the number of columns and rows differs from file to file. The task therefore is to load a general data table into the program and view it in the `DataGrid`.

My first attempt would have been to use a `DataTable`and bind it somehow to the `DataGrid`. However, after a while of searching, I read that using `DataTable` is not the best solution and one should use data models instead. Unfortunately, the most examples in the web use data with fixed data columns. Furthermore, I was not able to get the binding between `DataGrid` and `DataTable` to work properly. It would be very nice to be able to make changes to the data on both ends: the `DataGrid`(as the user would) and the underlying data structure (as the code would).

Please, can somebody explain, why the `DataTable` should not be use? What should be used instead to achieve the above behavior?

The data loading itself shouldn't be a problem, but how to store, handle and bind the data table in a flexible way to the `DataGrid`is.

The following code kind of works. However it seems to not respond to any changes to the data like adding rows or columns but the `DataTable` contains the right data.

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
 x:Name="myDataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding myDataTable}"  />
```

```cs
DataTable myDataTable  { get; private set; }
...
myDataGrid.DataContext = this;
LoadData();
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

I highly appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915840/binding-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-datatable ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution provided in that topic is actually the same as my "example". It is ok if the content of the cells are changed but fails if the rows or columns changing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigations I found a solution which is fine for me.  However, it feels to be a bit odd and not the best solution, but i can live with that. Thanks again for your effort which helped me a lot.

The idea is to refresh the `GridView` whenever a column has added/removed by unset/set the `DataContext` of the `GridView`. I use the `DataTable.Columns.CollectionChanged` event to achieve this behavior.

Now, almost everything is fine. The only issue that remains is when a new line is added by the user via the `GridView` (when clicking in the last empty row and type in data). Nevertheless, this is only a minor issue since the bound `DataTable` is updated correctly and only the second `GridView` (in the example below) is not displayed correctly.

The question stays, whether or not the usage of `DataTable` is the best solution. If the reseting of the `DataContext` causes trouble for large data sets needs to be tested...

Here is a complete example on the issue and the solution:

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Class="WpfApplicationTest.MainWindow"
         Title="DataGrid and DataTable Test" Height="500" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Click="ButtonRefresh_Click">Refresh Grids</Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonAddRow_Click">Add Row</Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonAddCol_Click">Add Col</Button>
            <Button Click="ButtonEdit_Click">Edit Randomly</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid0" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
            <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid1" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplicationTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DataTable myDataTable;
        private Random myRandom = new Random();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myDataTable = new DataTable();

            // create some datatable
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("First");
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("Second");
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(myRandom.Next(100).ToString(), myRandom.Next(100).ToString());
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(myRandom.Next(100).ToString(), myRandom.Next(100).ToString());

            myDataGrid0.DataContext = myDataTable;
            myDataGrid1.DataContext = myDataTable;

            myDataTable.Columns.CollectionChanged += Columns_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void Columns_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            // refresh the grid views by reseting the data context after the columns have changed
            myDataGrid0.DataContext = null;
            myDataGrid0.DataContext = myDataTable;
            myDataGrid1.DataContext = null;
            myDataGrid1.DataContext = myDataTable;
        }

        private void ButtonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // refresh the grid views by reseting the data context
            myDataGrid0.DataContext = null;
            myDataGrid0.DataContext = myDataTable;
            myDataGrid1.DataContext = null;
            myDataGrid1.DataContext = myDataTable;
        }

        private void ButtonAddRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // add rows with random content
            DataRow row = myDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; ++i)
                row[i] = myRandom.Next(100);
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        int rowcount = 0;
        private void ButtonAddCol_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // add columns with random content
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("New" + rowcount.ToString());
            foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
                row["New" + rowcount.ToString()] = myRandom.Next(100);
            ++rowcount;
        }

        private void ButtonEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // randomly change some data table values
            myDataTable.Rows[myRandom.Next(myDataTable.Rows.Count)][myRandom.Next(myDataTable.Columns.Count)] = myRandom.Next(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ItemsSource to a [BindingListCollectionView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx). I've had good luck so far with it. I use these extension methods:

```
  public static BindingListCollectionView GetCollectionView(this DataTable table)
        {
            return new BindingListCollectionView(table.DefaultView);
        }



 public static DataTable GetDataTable(this BindingListCollectionView view)
    {
        var dataView = view.SourceCollection as DataView;
        if (dataView != null)
        {
            return dataView.Table;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Use it in your code like:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.GetCollectionView();
```

and

```
var view = myDataGrid.ItemsSource as BindingListCollectionView;
var table = view.GetDataTable();
```

You should be able to use the DataTable object like you normally would with all of the changes  made by the grid preserved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But using a `BindingListCollectionView` instead of the `DataTable` (or `DataTable.DefaulView`) for the binding didn't make any difference...